# Where is a localSharedObject file stored on a Mac

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm working with localSharedObjects and want to inspect the files that are created on the user's machine. According the the documentation, localSharedObject files are stored on a Mac in the following location: /Users/username/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/web_domain/path_to_application/application_name/object_name.sol

When I try to find the file, I cannot even get to: /Users/username/Library
as the Library file does not exist in that location. Also, I've been searching for files with a .sol extension, but without success.
My question: Where can I find loaclSharedObject files on a Mac running 10.7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Library folder that Mac OS X 10.7 hides. Go to Finder, hold down the Option key and select the Go menu. The Library folder will then appear and you can select it. If you wish to have permanent access to it, you can drag it into the Finder sidebar, or there's a Terminal command to get it to show permanently:

chflags nohidden ~/Library